# Meteor collection folder structure

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

The [official Meteor doc](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection) says:

> Collections/# <- definitions of collections and methods on them (could
>   be models).

In my database I have a collection `universities`. So in my Collections folder I have `university.js`.
How to implement methods on collection, for example `find()`? I don't want to have all code in my `index.js`. I know I can have Meteor.methods and Meteor.call but that is for client - server invoke.

Comment: [find](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find) is automatically added to all collection instances. Do you mean something more specific to your collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe create a function like this. on whatever folder you want `/lib/collections` could be an option.

> for example find()

```
function findMethod(){
  return Collection.find();
}
```

and use it whatever you want.

```
var finde = findMethod();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So if I have already in my database collection universities and in my collections.js - University = new Mongo.Collection("university"), it will automatically bind?

Comment: Depends did you have the autopublish package? if you already remove it you should use the [publish(server)](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish)/[subscribe(client)](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe) methods

Comment: Thank you, I will check this answer. Just one more question, I've removed autopublish package and in my serve/publications.js I have Meteor.publish('universities', function() {
  return University.find();
}); In my application.js file I have subscribe method. My collection is loaded only first time, after refresh, collection just disappers. What's the catch?